# How to call URL which requires .pfx certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, client-certificates, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to call an URL which requires .pfx certificate installed on the system. 
Here is the code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;

public class PfxCertificate {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {

        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("path-to-.pfx-file")),
                "passwrd-for-pfx-file".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientStore, "passwrd-for-pfx-file".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("path-to-jks-file"), "password-for-jks-file".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

        URL url = new URL("URL");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        con.connect();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

I am getting error as at line :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

and the stackTrace is :

```
  Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at PfxCertificate.main(PfxCertificate.java:73)
```

What changes I should make in the code so that I can run it successfully?

Comment: Review the path to your truststore

Comment: Hi, it's correct. What else you can suggest? I have created new .jks file without importing any certificate in keyTool software..am I right?

Comment: You need to import at least the root of the server certificate

Comment: You mean .cer or .pfx file? Please mention.

Comment: You need to import in the trustore the root certificate of the server certificate. This part is public and is usually contained in a .cer or .pem file

Comment: This is my trustore path : /home/company/Downloads/keystore.jks
Have created keystore.jks file through keyStore tool by importing .cer file. Am I right? Please provide your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Try to debug the SSL connection with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`